# Bouncy Castle TLS API usage

Tags: c#, ssl, bouncycastle

I want to communicate between Server and Client using sockets using bouncy castle TLS library.
I went through many documentation(which was insufficient for me) but I did not get any idea how to do this,

I am using **BouncyCastle v1.7.48**(runtime version=v2.0.50727) binary,
and I have found these info,

I have to use, `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls` namespace and `TlsProtocolHandler` class.

To achieve TLS communication,

1. what API I should use in server side?
2. what API I should use in client side?

   ```
       System.IO.Stream inputStream, outputStream;
       TlsProtocolHandler tls = new TlsProtocolHandler(inputStream, outputStream);
   ```
3. What are the parameters `inputStream` and `outputStream`?

> **public virtual void Connect(TlsClient tlsClient);**

where, `TlsClient` is an **interface**, and that **contains many** interfaces **inside**.

**4. How to use the above API? I have to declare new classes and implement methods inside that to all?**

Please help me with this Bouncy Castle.

**EDIT 1:**
I created one class which inherits from an abstract class called `DefaultTlsClient`.
Then I could create an instance of my class and pass it for interface reference.
So I could send the parameter like this. `tls.Connect(tlsClient);`

I am not initializing any parameters except I mentioned above.
(Sockets are connected before these operation on 2055)
But I am not sure handshake is complete or not. My program will go to reading state.

Comment: I could not find any testcase which will use the above API.

Comment: Then you can use our SecureBlackbox - it comes with documentation, support and samples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no server-side TLS API in bouncy castle. You can read on main page that they support only client-side.

For client-side you have found right classes already. `TlsProtocolHandler` does the job, but it won't work without custom classes. Here is example code:

```
    // Need class with TlsClient in inheritance chain
    class MyTlsClient : DefaultTlsClient
    {
        public override TlsAuthentication GetAuthentication()
        {
            return new MyTlsAuthentication();
        }
    }

    // Need class to handle certificate auth
    class MyTlsAuthentication : TlsAuthentication
    {
        public TlsCredentials GetClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest)
        {
            // return client certificate
            return null;
        }

        public void NotifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate)
        {
            // validate server certificate
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

            client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 6000);

            // input/output streams are deprecated, just pass client stream
            TlsProtocolHandler handler = new TlsProtocolHandler(client.GetStream());

            handler.Connect(new MyTlsClient());

            // handshake completed
            // use handler.Stream.Write/Read for sending app data

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I have tested this with my tcp server and received client hello.

Keep in mind it is TLS in version 1.0 so if u need other version or server api then I recommend using other library (.NET framework supports TLS).

Comment: please validate this: **1. I want TLS v1.2, I cannot use Bouncy castle** `2. there is no server side api available for TLS means, Client side I can use Bouncy castle. But server side, I have to implement TLS on TCP by myslelf or using some libraries.(may be .net framework or some other)`

Comment: You can see in source code TlsProtocolHandler.cs "An implementation of all high level protocols in TLS 1.0" also that they send in header 0x0301 = version 1.0. I would use .NET [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) in both client and server.

Comment: In latest Bouncy Castle `TlsProtocolHandler` is deprecated, so use `TlsServerProtocol` or `TlsClientProtocol` with stream and `new SecureRandom()` as arguments.